# How can I change the meta tags name of 'csrf-param' and 'csrf-token' in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

As the title states, I wonder how I can change the meta tags name of `csrf-param` and `csrf-token`?

```
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="123456" name="csrf-token" />
```

I'm asking this, because for safety reason I want to hide, which technology I'm using to power my website. The Chrome plugin `Wappalyzer` uses this meta tags as indicators for `Ruby on Rails`.

[image]

Comment: It appears it could be as easy as a simple monkey patch to change the names. jquery_ujs could be another problem however. Rails defines it in `ActionView::Helpers::CsrfHelper` (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to change the part, where Rails receive the CSRF token?

Answer (score 1):

Create an initializer called `change_csrf_name.rb`

inside this file you can change the **`:name => 'xyz'`**. beware that it might break some built in functionality you were not expecting.

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module CsrfHelper
      def csrf_meta_tags
        if protect_against_forgery?
          [
            tag('meta', :name => 'csrf-param', :content => request_forgery_protection_token),
            tag('meta', :name => 'csrf-token', :content => form_authenticity_token)
          ].join("\n").html_safe
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need this meta tags sometimes for my JavaScripts, that they can send the CSRF Token to the serven on AJAX requests. Basically I just asked how to rename the `name` attribute of these meta tags.